# AFP connections dropping on 10.8.5 Server

Tags: macos, server.app

We are experiencing a very odd problem when AFP connections to our server are dropping part way through, which often then means the client machine crashes.

AFP logs on the server show nothing, but the /var/log/system.log events below show the disconnection as it happens.

Note I have installed the 10.8.5 Combo Updater, reinstalled the Server.app from the AppStore, tried various client machines, and experienced the same problem.

There is plenty of space on both sides and the folders in question are about 40GB.

Disk Warrior on both ends has been used already, nothing interesting found.

Oddly enough connecting via SMB does not cause these problems, so it appears AFP or network related, as far as I can tell.

```
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack.example.com KernelEventAgent[46]: tid 00000000 received event(s) VQ_NOTRESP (1)
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack.example.com KernelEventAgent[46]: tid 00000000 type 'afpfs', mounted on '/Volumes/INCOMING', from '//tony@ml.example.com/INCOMING', not responding
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: ASP_TCP Disconnect: triggering reconnect by bumping reconnTrigger from curr value 0 on so 0xffffff801e112ef0
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect started /Volumes/INCOMING prevTrigger 0 currTrigger 1
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  doing reconnect on /Volumes/INCOMING
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  posting to KEA EINPROGRESS for /Volumes/INCOMING
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Max reconnect time: 30 secs, Connect timeout: 15 secs for /Volumes/INCOMING
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  connect to the server /Volumes/INCOMING
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Logging in with uam 10 /Volumes/INCOMING
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack.example.com KernelEventAgent[46]: tid 00000000 found 1 filesystem(s) with problem(s)
Oct  7 18:28:14 sixpack kernel[0]: AFP_VFS afpfs_DoReconnect:  Restoring session /Volumes/INCOMING
```

Any suggestions or ideas most appreciated!

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue. We have network homes on 10.8.5 server and afp keeps getting disconnected. Our log outputs the same info. We will try SMB this morning to see if makes things any better.

Comment: Can we presume you don't see switching clients to SMB as a valid solution?

Comment: Yes, using SMB is the workaround but this also now means we can't do network Time Machine backups, because it is reliant on AFP.

Note I've now confirmed this is not a network-related problem as I directly connected a client to the server with an Ethernet cable, bypassing the switch, and experienced the same problem.

My guess now is that some bug was introduced in a recent OSX update.

Comment: I've tried reproducing this, but of the 45 clients connected over AFP to several servers, I'm not seeing any lockups or even abnormal disconnect rates. Any messages on the client logs at the same time as the server kernel errors?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this yet on other servers of the same build, so this should be considered intermittent. It must be some internal AFP database of files that is corrupt or problematic but it's very odd there are no errors on the server end when this happens. I've also seen the same behavior with clients on 10.6.8 so it seems to be on the server end and only with AFP, as SMB works fine.